# what neural network model for the picture below are supported by cntk?

Tags: neural-network, cntk

what neural network model for the picture below are supported by cntk?
which of them are supported by higher level API,and which are supported by core or lower level only?

neural network model:

[image: neural network model]

Comment: Author really needs to demonstrate having done some work on this question themselves, rather than just asking to be spoon fed information

Comment: I have learned some of these models,but for others ,I don't know how to construct the network,I  didn't go to find information about them because I have no time to left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description of the different components, all of these networks are supported. However, the ones that will be efficient to learn are the ones which are trained with gradient based methods. CNTK doesn't have built-in learners for RBMs and other models whose updates are not based on stochastic gradients. You could write those updates with user-defined learners though.

Comment: thank you very much. which of them can be down directly by cntk.layers like cnn which can use convolution() and dens() to construct its network structure?